# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un texto con números como si fuera un int en postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Necesito ordenar unos varchar que contienen numeros y letras

```
SELECT dnom FROM ws_sample_dev.cat_node WHERE nodetype_id='T'
  ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN dnom < 'A'
       THEN lpad(dnom, 16, '0') 
    ELSE dnom 
    END;
```

Esto es el valor obtenido:

```
110-110-63 mm
160-160-63 mm
200-160-160 mm
110-160-160 mm
63-63-63 mm
110-110-110 mm    
160-110-63 mm
63-63-110 mm
```

Y esto el valor deseado:

```
63-63-63 mm
63-63-110 mm
110-110-63 mm
110-110-110 mm
110-160-160 mm
160-110-63 mm
160-160-63 mm
200-110-160 mm
```

Comment: Hola Nestor. Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado junto a por qué no te funciona?

Comment: Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/87676/edit) la pregunta para añadir toda informacion relevante, no en los comentarios. Explica tambien por qué ese codigo no te funciona. errores? resultado no esperado ?